# Haskell read CSV file -> load XML file from url -> write out CSV file again

Tags: xml, csv, haskell, hxt

I am trying to

1. Load a CSV File
2. Read IDs from the file
3. Load an external xml file for each Id
4. Read some names from XML
5. Write out the ID and names into new CSV File

I am new to Haskell and really wanna learn it, I am still in the copy and paste phase of understanding. I have found tutorials for each part on its own, but I struggle with combining them.

The CSV is simple, like:

```
736572,"Mount Athos"
6697806,"North Aegean"
```

I use [Cassava](https://github.com/hvr/cassava) to read the CSV and [HandsomeSoup](https://github.com/egonSchiele/HandsomeSoup) for XML reading.

Here my attempt to read the id, load the xml and print the names from the xml at least.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.Vector as V

import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Text.HandsomeSoup

import Data.List
import Data.Char


getPlaceNames::String->String->String
getPlaceNames pid name = do
    let doc = fromUrl ("http://api.geonames.org/get?geonameId="++pid++"&username=demo")

    c<-runX $ doc >>> css "alternateNames" >>> deep getText
    return (head c)


main :: IO ()
main = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile "input.csv"
    case decode NoHeader csvData of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right v -> V.forM_ v $ \ ( pid, name ) ->
          putStrLn $  getPlaceNames pid name
```

I think I am doing something wrong when I call getPlaceNames and return the names. I am not even sure if I should use the 'do' statement in getPlaceNames.

Error says

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘[[Char]]’
            with actual type ‘IO [String]’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  c <- runX $ doc >>> css "alternateNames" >>> deep getText
In the expression:
  do { let doc
             = fromUrl
                 ("http://api.geonames.org/get?geonameId="
                  ++ pid ++ "&username=demo");
       c <- runX $ doc >>> css "alternateNames" >>> deep getText;
       return (head c) }
In an equation for ‘getPlaceNames’:
    getPlaceNames pid name
      = do { let doc = ...;
             c <- runX $ doc >>> css "alternateNames" >>> deep getText;
             return (head c) }
```

But thats probably just one thing that I am doing wrong because of my lack of understanding of monads and bindings.

Any help appreciated, even if its just a pointer to the right docs.

Cheers

Bjorn

Comment: Maybe you need `fromUrl ("http://api.geonames.org/get?geonameId="++pid++"&username=demo")`. Also, you should add a type signature to `getPlaceNames`: I guess once you declare what you need more errors will appear helping you to fix the code.

Comment: good call, I edited my post and added the type decleration and brackets.
The error message has changed now. Still don't understand whats wrong.

Comment: OK, now you need to return `IO [String]` in `getPlaceNames`, since you are running side effectful stuff there. Then, in `main` you need to `do pns <- getPlaceNames pid name ; putStrLn pns` or use `putStrLn <$> getPlaceNames pid name`

Comment: Great, you answered also another question I had in my head.
Nearly there, It removed all compile errors, but doesn't print anything in main.

I changed IO[String] to IO String though, as I am only using the first element of 'c'.

If I print it in getPlaceName I get a correct print. But when I print it in main I get nothing, not even an error.

I changed main to
 `Right v -> V.forM_ v $ \ ( pid, name ) ->
          putStrLn <$> (getPlaceNames pid name)`

Comment: Worked with `do pns <- getPlaceNames pid name ; putStrLn pns`

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. It actually cleared a lot of my confusion.

I will try to solve the writing to csv on my own and then post it here for others. If I get stuck, I'll let you know.

How can I give you credits on comments?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to chi I've figured out the whole procedure. I am posting my code for anyone else who needs to do something similar.

In the end I did not only take the names from the xml but multiple fields.
So I changed `getPlaceNames` to `gtPlaceDetails`.

I show the full code, because it also shows how I read different fields from the XML and how I merge `alternateName` elements in the XML to one String.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}


import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BL


import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.Vector as V

import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Text.HandsomeSoup
import Data.List
import Data.Char


uppercase :: String -> String
uppercase = map toUpper


toLanguageStr :: (String, String) -> String
toLanguageStr (lan,name) = uppercase lan ++ ":" ++ name


getPlaceDetails::String->String->IO (Int,String,Float,Float,Float,Float,Float,Float,String,String)
getPlaceDetails pid name = do
    let doc = fromUrl ("http://api.geonames.org/get?geonameId="++pid++"&username=demo")

    id<-runX $ doc >>> css "geonameId" >>> deep getText
    name<-runX $ doc >>> css "name" >>> deep getText
    s<- runX $ doc >>> css "south" >>> deep getText
    w<- runX $ doc >>> css "west" >>> deep getText
    n<- runX $ doc >>> css "north" >>>  deep getText
    e<- runX $ doc >>> css "east" >>> deep getText
    lat<- runX $ doc >>> css "lat" >>> deep getText
    lng<- runX $ doc >>> css "lng" >>> deep getText
    translations<- runX $ doc >>> css "alternateName" >>> (getAttrValue "lang" &&& (deep getText))
    terms<- runX $ doc >>> css "alternateNames" >>> deep getText
    return ( read (head id),head name, read (head lat), read (head lng), read (head s), read (head w), read (head n), read (head e), intercalate "|" $ map toLanguageStr translations, head terms )



main :: IO ()
main = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile "input.csv"
    case decode NoHeader csvData of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right v -> V.forM_ v $ \ ( pid, name )->do
            details <- getPlaceDetails pid name
            BL.appendFile "out.csv" $ encode [details]
            BL.putStrLn  (encode [details])
```

For example the input.csv line

`736572,"Mount Athos"`

maps into out.csv this

```
736572,"Mount Athos",40.15798,24.33021,40.11294,23.99234,40.4563,24.40044,"KO:아토스 산|:Aftónomos Periochí Agíou Órous|:Ágion Óros|:Ágio Óros|:Athos|NO:Áthos|EN:Autonomous Monastic State of the Holy Mountain|:Avtonómos Periokhí Ayíou Órous|:Áyion Óros|:Dhioíkisis Ayíou Órous|:Hagion Oros|:Holy Athonite Republic|LINK:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Athos|CA:Mont Athos|FR:Mont Athos|EN:Mount Athos|FR:République monastique du Mont Athos|EL:Αυτόνομη Μοναστική Πολιτεία Αγίου Όρους","Aftonomos Periochi Agiou Orous,Aftónomos Periochí Agíou Órous,Agio Oros,Agion Oros,Athos,Autonome Monastike Politeia Agiou Orous,Autonomous Monastic State of the Holy Mountain,Avtonomos Periokhi Ayiou Orous,Avtonómos Periokhí Ayíou Órous,Ayion Oros,Dhioikisis Ayiou Orous,Dhioíkisis Ayíou Órous,Hagion Oros,Holy Athonite Republic,Mont Athos,Mount Athos,Republique monastique du Mont Athos,République monastique du Mont Athos,atoseu san,Ágio Óros,Ágion Óros,Áthos,Áyion Óros,Αυτόνομη Μοναστική Πολιτεία Αγίου Όρους,아토스 산"
```

Comment: I'm not a HXT expert, but it looks as if every `runX $ doc >>> ....` queries the web, which is not too efficient. You could be able to do one single query by using e.g. `(x,y,z) <- runX $ doc >>> ((css "x" >>> deep getText) &&& (css "y" >>> deep getText) &&& (css "z" >>> deep getText))`, which calls `runX` exactly once. Again, I ever used HXT, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Not sure either, but I had yesterday the feeling that the it took pretty long to get the data for one entry. That would explain why.
I will try out your version and see if it works.

Comment: Tried it, didn't get it to work. If I understand you correctly you try to merge Arrows. The compiler complains then that types don't match as the expression would return tuples in tuples. Guess I have to know first how Arrows work.

`Couldn't match expected type ‘[(String, (String, String))]’
                with actual type ‘(t0, t1, t2)’
    In the pattern: (x, y, z)
`

Comment: Ah, my `(x,y,z) <- ...` is indeed wrong, it's likely `(x, (y,z)) <- ...` with nested pairs all the way `(x1, (x2, (x3, (...`

Comment: I see that it is returning a list... maybe you also need `(x, (y, z)) <- head $ runX $ ...` or using pattern matching over the list somehow. This could save you from using `head` afterwards (?)

Comment: The nested pairs makes it pretty ugly the more elements you query.
Damn there must be a really beautiful solution somhow.

I was also wondering if I can save the head.  But then, at least for one of the lists I need all of the children and not only head. I also didn't actually use `head` in the end, as the lists where sometimes empty. So I had to use a custom function that returns also a default value in case the list is empty. 

Tricky.

Pattern Matching ... hmm ... new territory for me. Will look into it.